# Sliding Scale Revenue Split

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> We have a product that we sell for the prices between $15,000$ and $30,000$ depending on various options and services. There is a company that wants to resell our product, and I'm keen to give them an incentive to sell more valuable packages. We have agreed a revenue split that is given below.

1. for a $15000$ product the reseller can add $4500$ on top ($30$%) for a total end price of $19500$
2. for a $30000$ product the reseller can add $12000$ on top ($40$%) for a total end price of $42000$

there should be a sliding scale between $30$% and $40$% depending on either the value of the product from us or the end price to the customer.

I'd like to be able to describe this mathematically so that I can code a little calculator for them but I'm really struggling to find an approach.

Ta, Andrew

Comment: Are you envisioning a linear relationship between the original price and the percent added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is to use [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Linear_interpolation_between_two_known_points). For your problem, we have $$\frac{y-30}{x-15000}=\frac{40-30}{30000-15000} \implies y = \frac{x}{1500}+20.$$
Here, $x$ is the product price (e.g. $x=15000,20000,25000$ etc.), and $y$ is the profit percentage.